# How to display hex code color in box?

Tags: php, html, css

I get the hex color value from the database per user and it shows in the box (picture beneath).
I want to show this color in a small box instead of the hex value.

**Code**

```
<dd class="fl br-1 lh36" style="width:73px">
<p class="ff-m f14" style="color: #ff4600"><b>COLOR</b></p>
<p class="ff-m f13"><?= $user_info['my_color']?></p>
</dd>
```

**Screenshot**

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to use an in-line style like you are for the COLOR header...

```
<dd class="fl br-1 lh36" style="width:73px">
<p class="ff-m f14" style="color: #ff4600"><b>COLOR</b></p>
<p class="ff-m f13" style="background-color:<?= $user_info['my_color']?>"></p>
</dd>
```

Comment: Thnx man did helped! but I have to put text after <?= $user_info['my_color']?>"  >here i have to put text</p> otherwise the color is not visible so i put a dot there. Do you know how to make that transparent or not visible so you only see the color ?

Comment: Unless you have to, don't use the <p> tag, use a div and give it some dimensions

`<div class="ff-m f13" style="width:50px; height:50px; background-color:<?= $user_info['my_color']?>"></div>`

You could either define that in the 'ff-m f13' class, or do it inline (I'd recommend in the class). If you have to use <p> tags, then you can perhaps put a div inside the <p></p>